# How to address the log INFO Using `new FirefoxOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()` in selenium project

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I just started a selenium project, but things didn't got right, so after searching a bit I found this solution. It works but i can't understand what these red statements want me to do, or how to get rid of them.

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.io.*;

public class SelTest1
{
    public  static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","X:\\Gecko\\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

        File pathBinary = new File("X:\\FireFoxx\\firefox.exe");
        FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);
        DesiredCapabilities desired = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        desired.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS, options.setBinary(firefoxBinary));
        WebDriver obj = new FirefoxDriver(options);

        obj.get("http://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

[image: This image has those red lines]

I got the result i wanted, but I don't understand the warning{ red statements}

I am putting those red lines { warnings here too for ease  }

```
Jul 12, 2019 7:07:28 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities firefox
INFO: Using `new FirefoxOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()`
1562938650997   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "X:\\FireFoxx\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\adars\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.uTUmeENutxin"
1562938652637   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1562938652638   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1562938652638   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
1562938655909   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 50040
1562938655964   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Jul 12, 2019 7:07:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

Comment: your example needlessly calls DesiredCapabilities.firefox() ... you never even use it, so just remove that line to get rid of the first info message ...the rest of those can be ignored.

Comment: without that, it shows this " Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: WIN10" , and I did add the path, and i won't reinstall firefox in it's default location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *INFO* log message:

```
INFO: Using `new FirefoxOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()`
```

is the result of the changes incorporated in:

- *Selenium v3.0.0-beta4*

  ```
  Added ability to use FirefoxOptions when starting firefox.
  ```
- *Selenium v3.5.0*

  ```
  * Start making *Option classes instances of Capabilities. This allows
    the user to do:

    `WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new InternetExplorerOptions());`
  ```

---

If your usecase is to explicitly mention the absolute location of the `FirefoxBinary` you can use the following solution:

- Using `FirefoxOptions`:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

  public class A_Firefox_binary 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
          FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
          options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
          WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
          System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Page Title is : Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
  ```